# Vaadin Flow: Best practise for hiding fields / change labels in FormLayout

Tags: label, vaadin, visibility, vaadin-flow, form-layout

What is the best practise for following code snippet...

```
public class Panel {

    private final TextField textField1 = new TextField();
    private final TextField textField2 = new TextField();
    private final TextArea textArea1 = new TextArea();
    private final TextArea textArea2 = new TextArea();

... many other fields

    private final Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox();
    private final Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox();


    public Component getContent() {
        FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
        layout.addFormItem(textField1, "label for textfield 1");
        layout.addFormItem(textField2, "label for textfield 2");

...        

        layout.addFormItem(cb1, "label for checkbox 1");
        layout.addFormItem(cb2, "label for checkbox 2");
        return layout;
    }
    
    public void updateFields(boolean predicate) {
        textField1.setVisible(predicate);
        textField2.setVisible(!predicate);

        textArea1.setLabel(predicate ? "label A" : "label B");
...

        cb1.setVisible(predicate);
        cb2.setVisible(!predicate);
    }
}
```

It looks not very practically to save all form-item-references from "FormLayout#addFormItem" to update the visibility state of the fields...
It is also not very practical to separate the labels from the fields.. In Vaadin8 it was simply possible to save the label at the field and it was used for the FormLayout...

Did I miss a point?!?
Is there a better Opportunity to get the advantages of a FormLayout but with the "original" Labels of the fields?!

edit:
https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/3352

Comment: You only need to call addFormItem if you want to have the label on the left. If you want the label on top you can set the label on the component

Comment: @SimonMartinelli that is, what i meant with "advantages of a formlayout".. to have the label on the left, the field on the right... otherwise i could also use any other html-container...

Comment: That's not the only advantage.. But what is exactly your use case?

Comment: I want to hide several fields, depending of some conditions... 
I want to use the labels of the fields for validation proposals (It's easier to create an error message with "validation for field " + field.getLabel() + " failed"....)
I want to change field labels dynamically, depending on changed conditions from other fields...
And I want the behaviour of Vaadin8's FormLayout with labels on the left, and fields on the right... without rewriting the complete css for any component I use...

Comment: Custom components could know their own labels, but they can't be used in FormLayouts.. I have to "copy" them and remove them from the component, if i want to use them in the layout

Comment: For all of that you can use the FormItem you create

Comment: but for that I need additional formitem-references for every field i use... 
i can't use custom component labels, and if i want to change a label, i need the formitem, not the field i have... (for example, i have a getter for the text field, i also need a getter "getFormItem(Component c)" if i want to change the label or the visibility state for the field!?

--- so it is not possible to do it in another way? That's what you want to say!?

Comment: No it's not possible to do it in another way

Comment: mhmm.. ok. But many thanks for your efforts..

Comment: You should open a feature request: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues